# Releasing Memory from MapView

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, mkmapview

In my project I am using a mapView to render locations from Lat-Lon received from an API. My project has a button which does the follow:

1. When clicked, it fires a timer that retrieves coordinates from the web and then plots on the mapview
2. When clicked again, it stops the timer and no data is retrieved.

However even when the timer is stopped it consumes a lot of memory around 100mbs if not more. So I want to release the memory when user is not using map and when they are map should come back again. I did the following to release memory:

```
            self.mapView.delegate = nil;
            self.mapView.removeFromSuperview()
            self.mapView = nil;
```

This removes map and my memory comes back to 20mbs, normal. However *is this the correct way to release memory*? and *how do I get it back once the button is pressed*?.

Comment: Yes this is correct. MapView is pretty resource heavy, which is why it consumes a lot of a memory so 100+ Mb increase in memory usage is pretty normal if you are doing something heavy

Comment: @VisalRajapakse Alright thankyou for confirming. Once I do self.mapView=nil. It removes the map, How do I get it back after that?

Comment: Are you using `Storyboards`? if so, removing the `delegate` should do the trick as ARC will do the rest for you. If you are doing it programmatically, you can use`addSubview(_:)` on the mapview in the `viewWillAppear(_:)` method and deinitialize the mapview in `viewDidDisappear(_:)`. Also if you want to be certain that your ViewController is deinitialized, add the `deinit()` method with an embedded print statement. In my experience its the delegates that prevent the Viewcontroller from being deinitialized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To add a map you can do this**:

import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
var mapView: MKMapView?

@IBOutlet weak var framer: UIView!//uiview to put map into

var coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(){
    willSet{
        print("removing annotation...")
        if let m = mapView{
        m.removeAnnotation(anno)
        }
    }
    didSet{
        print("did set called, adding annotation...")
        
        anno.coordinate = coordinate
        if let m = mapView{
        m.addAnnotation(anno)
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {

    
    super.viewDidLoad()        
}
```

```
    @IBAction func start(_ sender: Any) {
        let mk = MKMapView()
        
        mk.bounds = framer.bounds
        
        mk.mapType = MKMapType.standard
        mk.isZoomEnabled = true
        mk.isScrollEnabled = true
        
        // Or, if needed, we can position map in the center of the view
        mk.center = framer.center
        mapView = mk
        if let mk2 = mapView{
        framer.addSubview(mk2)
    }
}
```

**To remove**

```
    @IBAction func stop(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        if  mapView != nil{
            if let mk2 = mapView{
                mk2.delegate = nil;
                mk2.removeFromSuperview()
                mapView = nil;
                
    }
        }
    }
}
```